# ERROR: Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

The error occurs on Line 5 where I try to `SUM(genre) AS "Total"`.

I've tried `convert`ing `genre` to `int` or `cast`ing as `int`, both led to an Action error.

```
USE IMDB
SELECT
    CAST(genre AS CHAR(20)) AS "Genre",
    COUNT (genre) AS "Count",
    SUM (genre) AS "Total"
    /*STR(100*COUNT (genre) / SUM(SUM( genre)) OVER (), 6, 2) + '%' AS "Percent"*/
FROM title_genre
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY "Count" DESC;
```

Comment: What is the content of column `genre` ? If it contains something else than a number, how do you want to handle that in your `SUM()` ?

Comment: My genre column contains the name of genre's like "drama, action, etc". My first select statement get's the list of genres, second gets the number of shows in that genre so with my third statement I am trying to get the total number of shows overall across all genres.

Comment: Hi, I believe the problem is relly present, but it's not so clear all the underneath. please follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn more how to ask proper question

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. How does one sum a string? What is the sum of the values `'ahsaf'`, `'asdfaksjbdk'` and `'asdjkasd'`? You can't work it out as they're strings; SQL Server is not different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total across all genres, then use window functions:

```
SELECT CAST(genre AS CHAR(20)) AS Genre,
       COUNT(*) as cnt,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as total
FROM title_genre
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY "Count" DESC;
```

For the proportion, you would use:

```
(COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) as proportion
```

Comment: That did the trick, a windowed function is exactly what I needed, I am new to SQL so I greatly appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Also, when trying to add + '%' after defining it as proportion so my results have a % symbol in it, I get an error. 

Error: Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: @user11036217 . . . You need to convert the value to a string to append a "%".

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing exactly that and got it working, I appreciate all your help.

Example:
STR(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (),6,2) + '%' AS "Percent"

Comment: If your issue is resolved consider to mark this post as the answer